# О произношении

Tags: фонетика

Может быть, это глупый вопрос или совсем не по теме. Если что, скажите. Просто, слушая радиопостановки, сделанные в середине 20 века (например, когда тексты читала Мария Бабанова), я обратила внимание, что там подчеркнуто не произносили мягкий знак на конце. Например, говорили "смеркалос", "показалос". Почему так? Разве тогда были такие нормы произношения? Ведь за дикцией чтецов тогда очень следили, и я не помню, чтобы в быту кто-нибудь говорил так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ДА, тогда были такие нормы. Это старое московское произношение. Мягкость появилась под влиянием "всеобщей грамотности" (чтения). Красивое было произношение. А еще твердые согласные на конце корня в прилагательных (высокий как произносилось высокъй) - тоже изменилось под влиянием чтения.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё верьхь, зьдесь...
Под влиянием чтения скоро "умрут" конеШно, скуШно,
мы все будем говорить конеЧно, скуЧно и даже Что((